# Html newbie! background-image question

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML and I wanted to practice by recreating a invoice sent to me by Electronics Expo.

However, I used the background-image property and repeated it by repeat-x and now, the background stretches across the page so much that it has a horizontal bar to drag.

http://htmlpocketreference.110mb.com/index.html

You can see what I did in my link above.

Also, I would really appreciate some advice on simplifying my CSS coding. It seems really messy and I have to move every element once something changes. -.-

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you have relatively positioned elements that do not have a fixed width - these elements take on the width of their parents, which is the width of your invoice, and stick out of the page, causing the overflow. Give them a background color, and you can see this quite clearly:

[image]

Give the elements a fixed width to fix this, or alternatively, look to other methods of laying out your elements, like floating them.

---

In addition to this problem, you're also repeating the `id` attribute, which is creating invalid HTML. You should look at using the `class` attribute for multiple elements sharing the same style, or even better, look at using inheritance and the cascade to not have to give *every single* element an `id`.

Further reading:

- [CSS Positioning 101](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/)
- [Inheritance and Cascade from The Web Standards Curriculum](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/28-inheritance-and-cascade/)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not the background. The problem is the position relative you're giving to the block level elements without defining their width...

The h2 elements like (Ship To:) and (Phone) and all the paragraph elements. You need to give these elements a specific width and it will work fine

Try giving these elements a background-color: yellow; to see how the flow inside the document ( for your debugging purpose ) and you will see what I mean

Comment: The above suggestion to add a background color is a debugging tip, not the answer to the question.  read further in that answer for the answer.